Behaviour of the solutions of parametrized multivariable non-linear (non polynomial) system of equations
The following problem arose out of a research problem. Let us consider the $n \times n$ matrix valued function $[x_{i,j}(p)]$ (of $p$),  satisfying
$$ \sum_j x_{i,j}(p) x_{k,j}(p)|x_{k,j}(p)|^{p}= \delta_{i, k}$$
For $i=k$, these conditions in particular say that rows of the matrix $[x_{i,j}(p)]$ has unit $l_{p+2}$ norm.
We are able to establish the finiteness of the solution for fixed $p> 0$ in the following article
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.00664. We are further trying to see what we can say about the behaviour of the entries $x_{i,j}(p)$ as $p$ varies. For example, we expect that for $p>0$,they should be monotone. This has been observed in dimension $3$ explicitly, and also supported by the intuition that the unit $l_p$  ball inflates in a particular fashion as $p$ increases.
But we are not able reason it. We failed to also trace any discussion of a  similar system of equations in the literature. Can someone please shed light onto the problem or suggest some reference.

Your system seems to resemble a nonlinear eigenvalue problem and variational methods in L_p space. Look in texts relating to nonlinear functional analysis, convex analysis and monotonicity and spectral theory for nonlinear operators

@DanielCazares I would like to have more specific reference. There is large number of literatures on the subjects you have mentioned, it is very hard for a non-expert to go through them and find the relevant information.

See if these help: https://folk.ntnu.no/lqvist/p-laplace.pdf
Zeidler, Eberhard. “Nonlinear Functional Analysis and its Applications II/B: Nonlinear Monotone Operators.” Springer-Verlag, 1990.
Lemmens, Bas, and Roger Nussbaum. “Nonlinear Perron–Frobenius Theory.” Cambridge University Press, 2012.
Albiac, Fernando, and Nigel J. Kalton. “Topics in Banach Space Theory.” Springer, 2006.

@DanielCazares Could you say why the Albiac and Kalton book is supposed to be relevant? I am assuming that since you recommended it, you are somewhat familiar with the contents...
